# Azure IoT Hub and Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to use Xamarin.Forms Android and UWP with the IoT Hub? How? I can't find a functioning example. Windows.Azure.Devices.Clint works, but only for UWP (for me at least). What to do? Is it possible to use Windows.Azure.Devices.Clint, or do I have to use Windows.Azure.Devices.Clint.PCL?

Some things from the logs (might be helpful):

> Ignoring C:\Users\Korisnik.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.4.0\ref

And when trying to deploy:

> 03-30 10:09:33.202 D/Mono    (16948): Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe'.
>
> 03-30 10:09:33.203 F/monodroid-assembly(16948): Could not load assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe' during startup registration.
>
> 03-30 10:09:33.203 F/monodroid-assembly(16948): This might be due to an invalid debug installation.
>
> 03-30 10:09:33.203 F/monodroid-assembly(16948): A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.

Check out the repo with the sample code: https://github.com/ChakraSpice/Xamarin-IoT-Android-Issue-Sample (use your own connection string)

I can't deploy it to the android devices.

Answer (score 0):

It was a known issue but has already been fixed. Please check these issues: [[1]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/205) and [[2]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/106).

I install Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client version 1.7.0 in Xamarin.Forms Android. It seems working. You can try to see if it helps.

[image]

Comment: I install the package just fine, and build it too. Problems start when I want to deploy my app to the device. DeBug and Release mode - none deploy successfully so that I can actually test the app on my phone.

Comment: @Shocky2, this is a known issue in [xamarin.android](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1196), for now, the only known workaround is to **use `packages.config` instead of `<PackageReference>` when referencing from `NuGet`**.

Comment: @Shocky2, it should be fixed soon by [#1356](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/1356).

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Thank you!